# Where to download ABI interfaces in JSON with minimum requirements?

Tags: abi

Sorry for what I'm sure is a beginner question, but where can I dowwnload the ABIs in JSON format for only minimum required methods?  I can't seem to find it anywhere on Google.

For example, ERC721.  I have four different ABIs sitting here for ERC721, and they're all different.

Is there anywhere on the internet I can get these ABIs in JSON format, but which only contain the minimum method calls required for the token to be considered as satisfying that ABI?  All the other ones I seem to find always have optional methods added into them.

Need the JSON format though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.